# No close wizard report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, wizard

I have a wizard with a button that has this code:

```
@api.multi
def btn_print_report(self):
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'report',
        'nodestroy': True,
    }
```

But when you print the report closes the wizard, ie disappears and I have to open it again.
I would like the wizard will not close.